# Install Broadcom Wireless Drivers PCI ID 4464

Tags: 18.04, drivers, broadcom

I have Ubuntu 18.04 running on an iMac 27 inch 2019 model. Works fine (had to blacklist thunderbolt in the boot options) but Broadcom Card not working.

I followed the instructions [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/55868/installing-broadcom-wireless-drivers) desipte my PCI ID not being listed.

Output of `lspci -vnn | grep Network` is

```
Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries BCM4364 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter [14e4:4464] (rev 03)
```

Is there any support for this?

EDIT:

As requested the output from

`sudo modprobe brcmfmac && dmesg | grep brcm`

```
[    4.738706] usbcore: registered new interface driver brcmfmac
[    4.738726] brcmfmac 0000:03:00.0: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
[    4.844774] brcmfmac: brcmf_fw_alloc_request: using brcm/brcmfmac4364-pcie for chip BCM4364/3
[    4.851663] brcmfmac 0000:03:00.0: Direct firmware load for brcm/brcmfmac4364-pcie.bin failed with error -2
[    4.884406] Modules linked in: snd_intel_dspcfg snd_usb_audio snd_hda_codec intel_rapl_common snd_hda_core applesmc(+) snd_usbmidi_lib mc snd_hwdep snd_pcm x86_pkg_temp_thermal iommu_v2 intel_powerclamp gpu_sched coretemp snd_seq_midi ttm snd_seq_midi_event drm_kms_helper snd_rawmidi kvm_intel cec snd_seq rc_core kvm drm snd_seq_device crct10dif_pclmul brcmfmac snd_timer crc32_pclmul ghash_clmulni_intel aesni_intel hci_uart i2c_algo_bit crypto_simd fb_sys_fops snd btqca cryptd syscopyarea cdc_ether glue_helper brcmutil sysfillrect mei_me btrtl usbnet rapl apple_mfi_fastcharge(+) mii sysimgblt cfg80211 soundcore acpi_als intel_lpss_pci btbcm mei intel_cstate intel_pch_thermal intel_lpss btintel idma64 kfifo_buf bluetooth virt_dma efi_pstore industrialio apple_bl ecdh_generic ecc acpi_tad mac_hid sch_fq_codel parport_pc ppdev lp parport ip_tables x_tables autofs4 hid_apple hid_generic usbhid hid ses enclosure scsi_transport_sas uas usb_storage sdhci_pci nvme cqhci tg3 xhci_pci ahci sdhci
[    4.884440]  brcmf_fweh_detach+0x19/0x70 [brcmfmac]
[    4.884444]  brcmf_detach+0xa0/0x160 [brcmfmac]
[    4.884449]  brcmf_pcie_remove+0x78/0x140 [brcmfmac]
[    4.884457]  brcmf_pcie_setup+0x25/0x370 [brcmfmac]
[    4.884461]  brcmf_fw_request_done+0x73/0x100 [brcmfmac]
[    4.884481] WARNING: CPU: 13 PID: 191 at drivers/net/wireless/broadcom/brcm80211/brcmfmac/fweh.c:309 brcmf_fweh_detach+0x63/0x70 [brcmfmac]
[    4.884481] Modules linked in: snd_intel_dspcfg snd_usb_audio snd_hda_codec intel_rapl_common snd_hda_core applesmc(+) snd_usbmidi_lib mc snd_hwdep snd_pcm x86_pkg_temp_thermal iommu_v2 intel_powerclamp gpu_sched coretemp snd_seq_midi ttm snd_seq_midi_event drm_kms_helper snd_rawmidi kvm_intel cec snd_seq rc_core kvm drm snd_seq_device crct10dif_pclmul brcmfmac snd_timer crc32_pclmul ghash_clmulni_intel aesni_intel hci_uart i2c_algo_bit crypto_simd fb_sys_fops snd btqca cryptd syscopyarea cdc_ether glue_helper brcmutil sysfillrect mei_me btrtl usbnet rapl apple_mfi_fastcharge(+) mii sysimgblt cfg80211 soundcore acpi_als intel_lpss_pci btbcm mei intel_cstate intel_pch_thermal intel_lpss btintel idma64 kfifo_buf bluetooth virt_dma efi_pstore industrialio apple_bl ecdh_generic ecc acpi_tad mac_hid sch_fq_codel parport_pc ppdev lp parport ip_tables x_tables autofs4 hid_apple hid_generic usbhid hid ses enclosure scsi_transport_sas uas usb_storage sdhci_pci nvme cqhci tg3 xhci_pci ahci sdhci
[    4.884496] RIP: 0010:brcmf_fweh_detach+0x63/0x70 [brcmfmac]
[    4.884505]  brcmf_detach+0xa0/0x160 [brcmfmac]
[    4.884509]  brcmf_pcie_remove+0x78/0x140 [brcmfmac]
[    4.884515]  brcmf_pcie_setup+0x25/0x370 [brcmfmac]
[    4.884519]  brcmf_fw_request_done+0x73/0x100 [brcmfmac]
[    5.641108] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM: 'brcm/BCM.hcd'
```

Comment: Please edit your question to show the result of the terminal command: `sudo modprobe brcmfmac && dmesg | grep brcm` Firmware missing?? Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: Amazing thak you it did work, I scoured the web for ages for that so many thanks for pointing me in the right direction. Perhaps it is out of the scope for this question but is there a similar fix available for getting apple soundcards to work?

Comment: I suggest that you ask a new question about the soundcard. Glad the wireless is working!